# HBase filter rows using SingleColumnValueFilter

Tags: hadoop, filter, hbase

I have a HBase Table where I have a column qualifier which stores the created time as a long(convert to bytes array). I need to count the number of rows by filtering all the rows where created time is between the specified dates. Below is my java code.

```
    int count = 0;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
    HTable table = (HTable)connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
    long startTime = dateFormat.parse(startDate).getTime();
    long endTime = dateFormat.parse(endDate).getTime();

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    SingleColumnValueFilter filter1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(ConstantsTruthy.CF_DETAIL_BYTES, ConstantsTruthy.QUAL_CREATE_TIME_BYTES, CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(startTime));
    filter1.setFilterIfMissing(true);
    SingleColumnValueFilter filter2= new SingleColumnValueFilter(ConstantsTruthy.CF_DETAIL_BYTES, ConstantsTruthy.QUAL_CREATE_TIME_BYTES, CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(endTime));
    filter2.setFilterIfMissing(true);
    FilterList fl = new FilterList( FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
    fl.addFilter(filter1);
    fl.addFilter(filter2);
    scan.addFamily(ConstantsTruthy.CF_DETAIL_BYTES);
    scan.setFilter(fl);
    ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(scan);
    for (Result result = rs.next(); result != null; result = rs.next()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Count : " + count);
    rs.close();
    table.close();
```

This code runs without any errors. But the rows it returns only belong to a specific time. It does not contain all the rows in the time range. Could someone help me to figure out the problem with my filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks perfect.

We have tried the same and it is working even now also.

Could you please verify your input "startDate" and "endDate" once again.

Also what is the hbase version which you are using?

Comment: We are using HBase-1.2. Date saved in HBase table comes in the format of "Sun Aug 29 15:10:46 +0000 2010" and we convert it to a long before saving to the table. Start date and end date come as "2010-10-10" and I again convert it to long and use it as the start date and end date. Do you think different date format might causing the issue ?

Comment: I figured the problem is with the conversion of start date and end date. Once I fixed it, it is working as expected. Thanks Vijayakumar.